# Counting html tag length using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I have an html string like this:

```
<span class="1"><br>hi how<br>are</span><span>you?</span><br>
```

and a text string: "hi how are you?"

I have a number n, for example 4.
In the text string, the 4th character (counting from 0) is the "o".
I would like to take, using tag_count(), the same character from the html string.
In that case, variation should be 20, but i doesn't work.

```
var string="<span class="1"><br>hi how<br>are</span><span>you?</span><br>";
var c=4+tag_count(4,string);


function tag_count(n,string) {
    var variation=0;
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++) {
        if(string.charAt(i)=="<") {
            var j=0;
            while((string.charAt(i+j)!=">")&&(string.charAt(i+j)!==undefined)) {
                j++;
            }
            n=n+j+1;
            variation=variation+j+1;
        }
    }
    return(variation);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this:

1. Replace all tags with an empty string using `regex` and `replace`.
2. Output character position with `charAt`.

Regex to find tags:

```
var tags = /<+?.*?>/g;
```

In words: Find everything from `<` to `>`. The `?` after `*` means that it is `non greedy`, so that every tag can be found. Without `?` it would be greedy and one would only find one tag, which is the whole html. Replace the match with an empty string:

```
var str = html.replace(tags, "");
```

**Complete JavaScript**

```js
var html = "<span class='one1'><br>hi how<br>are</span><span>you?</span><br>";

function charAtHtmlText(html, n) {
    var tags = /<+?.*?>/g;
    var str = html.replace(tags, "");
    var res = str.charAt(n);
    return res;
}

var res = charAtHtmlText(html, 4);
alert(res);
// console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do this:

```
var string="<span class="1"><br>hi how<br>are</span><span>you?</span><br>";
var length = $(string).find('*').andSelf().length;
console.log(length);
```